# NSPredicate getting error with CoreData -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I can't find whats wrong in syntax . I cross check with apple documentation as well.

```
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "imageID = %@", imgID);
```

attached screenshot 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you post your code as image, noone can edit your code to fix it.

Comment: @Desdenova I added code line as well. screenshot only to show error .

Comment: @BilawalLiaqat But to find the right answer one had to open your link and to look for the type of `imgID`. You *should* have posted as text. You can post as image, but you *have to* also post as text, Desdenova is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define `ImgID` as `Double`, but the predicate format uses the specifier for an object `%@`. So, you should either be passing an `NSNumber` or using `%f` in the format.

If the `ImgID` is actually a double then you may have some issue getting an exact match. In this case you should either convert the id to a different data type, or range check (using < and >).